# Starting server for integration test fails

Tags: java, maven, jetty, jax-rs

I just started to write my first Jax-RS webservice and since yesterday I try to figure out how I can start a test server automatically if I build the project using maven. If I run the following commands without trying to execute some tests, everything works fine:

```
mvn clean install
export PORT=5000
java -cp target/classes:"target/dependency/*" net.avedo.spozz.Spozz
```

The service is then available at localhost:5000/services/users. But if I try to start a server and run test automatically by using the pom.xml I attached at the end of this post, I get an error:

```
testHasUser(net.avedo.spozz.models.UserTest): Connection refused
```

Which corresponds to this piece of code:

```
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("http://localhost:5000/services/users/1") ;
response = httpClient.execute(httpGet) ;
```

So, I am not sure what is wrong here. I think the server is started under the wrong uri, but as I am not telled where the test server is started, I cannot verify this. I need to know what I need to add or change in the pom.xml file, in order to run the test server to run the tests for the project. As it may help, here is my project structure:

```
   |-pom.xml
   |-src
   |---main
   |-----java
   |-------net
   |---------avedo
   |-----------spozz
   |-------------Spozz.java
   |-------------models
   |---------------User.java
   |-------------services
   |---------------UserResource.java
   |-----resources
   |-----webapp
   |-------index.html
   |-------WEB-INF
   |---------web.xml
   |---test
   |-----java
   |-------net
   |---------avedo
   |-----------spozz
   |-------------models
   |---------------UserTest.java
   |-----resources
   |-target
   |---classes
   |-----net
   |-------avedo
   |---------spozz
   |-----------Spozz.class
   |-----------models
   |-------------User.class
   |-----------services
   |-------------UserResource$1.class
   |-------------UserResource$2.class
   |-------------UserResource.class
   |---test-classes
   |-----net
   |-------avedo
   |---------spozz
   |-----------models
   |-------------UserTest.class
```

**My old pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>net.avedo.spozz</groupId>
    <artifactId>Spozz-Service</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Spozz REST Webservice</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Jetty -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>7.6.0.v20120127</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-webapp</artifactId>
            <version>7.6.0.v20120127</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Jersey -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
            <version>1.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
            <version>1.8</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- jUnit -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.10</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Apache Commons -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jetty-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>6.1.10</version>
                <configuration>
                    <scanIntervalSeconds>10</scanIntervalSeconds>
                    <stopKey>foo</stopKey>
                    <stopPort>5000</stopPort>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>start-jetty</id>
                        <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>run</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <scanIntervalSeconds>0</scanIntervalSeconds>
                            <daemon>true</daemon>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>stop-jetty</id>
                        <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>stop</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals><goal>copy-dependencies</goal></goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
    </plugins>

        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>

                <!-- M2Eclipse Compatibility -->
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                    <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.0</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                            <pluginExecutions>
                                <pluginExecution>
                                    <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                                        <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                                        <versionRange>[2.4,)</versionRange>
                                        <goals>
                                            <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                                        </goals>
                                    </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <action>
                                        <execute />
                                    </action>
                                </pluginExecution>
                            </pluginExecutions>
                        </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
</project>
```

**\\EDIT (1):**

I updated my `pom.xml` to use a newer version of jetty, but now I am getting new errors:

```
2014-03-06 11:51:29.126:WARN:oejuc.AbstractLifeCycle:FAILED org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler@66cbe14a:
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/jetty/servlet/FilterMapping
```

Furthermore the port problem pops up again:

```
Error binding monitor port 8080: java.net.BindException: Address already in use
2014-03-06 11:51:24.909:INFO:oejs.Server:jetty-8.1.14.v20131031
2014-03-06 11:51:25.245:INFO:oejpw.PlusConfiguration:No Transaction manager found - if your webapp requires one, please configure one.
2014-03-06 11:51:26.839:WARN:oejsh.RequestLogHandler:!RequestLog
2014-03-06 11:51:26.847:INFO:oejs.AbstractConnector:Started SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:28080
```

**My updated pom.xml**

```
<project 
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>net.avedo.spozz</groupId>
    <artifactId>Spozz-Webservice</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <jetty.version>9.1.0.v20131115</jetty.version>
        <jersey.version>1.8</jersey.version>
        <junit.version>4.11</junit.version>
        <apache.commons.version>1.3.2</apache.commons.version>
        <apache.http.version>4.3.2</apache.http.version>
        <jsp.version>2.5</jsp.version>
        <maven.compiler.plugin.version>2.5.1</maven.compiler.plugin.version>
        <sql.maven.plugin.version>1.5</sql.maven.plugin.version>
        <postgresql.jdbc.version>9.1-901.jdbc4</postgresql.jdbc.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Jetty -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-webapp</artifactId>
            <version>${jetty.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-jsp</artifactId>
            <version>${jetty.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>org.eclipse.jdt.core</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty.orbit</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Jersey -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- jUnit -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Apache Commons -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>${apache.commons.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>${apache.http.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- PostgreSQL -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>${postgresql.jdbc.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
                <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>8.1.14.v20131031</version>
                <configuration>
                    <scanIntervalSeconds>10</scanIntervalSeconds>
                    <stopKey>foo</stopKey>
                    <stopPort>8080</stopPort>
                    <stopWait>10</stopWait>

                    <connectors>
                        <connector implementation="org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio.SelectChannelConnector">
                            <port>28080</port>
                            <maxIdleTime>60000</maxIdleTime>
                        </connector>
                    </connectors>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>start-jetty</id>
                        <phase>test-compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>run</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <scanIntervalSeconds>0</scanIntervalSeconds>
                            <daemon>true</daemon>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>stop-jetty</id>
                        <phase>test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>stop</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>sql-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${sql.maven.plugin.version}</version>

                <dependencies>
                    <!-- Specify the dependent jdbc driver here -->
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
                        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
                        <version>${postgresql.jdbc.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>

                <!-- Common configuration shared by all executions -->
                <configuration>
                    <driver>org.postgresql.Driver</driver>
                    <url>jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432:spozz_db</url>
                    <username>postgres</username>
                    <password>root</password>
                    <!-- You can comment out username/password configurations and have 
                        maven to look them up in your settings.xml using ${settingsKey} -->
                    <settingsKey>sensibleKey</settingsKey>
                    <!-- All executions are ignored if -Dmaven.test.skip=true -->
                    <skip>${maven.test.skip}</skip>
                </configuration>

                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>drop-schema-before-test-if-any</id>
                        <phase>process-test-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>execute</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <!-- Need another database to drop the targeted one -->
                            <url>jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432:postgres</url>
                            <autocommit>true</autocommit>
                            <sqlCommand>DROP SCHEMA spozz CASCADE</sqlCommand>
                            <!-- Ignore error when database is not available -->
                            <onError>continue</onError>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>

                    <execution>
                        <id>create-schema</id>
                        <phase>process-test-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>execute</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <autocommit>true</autocommit>
                            <srcFiles>
                                <srcFile>src/main/sql/spozz-schema.sql</srcFile>
                            </srcFiles>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>

                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>dbunit-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.0-beta-3</version>

                <dependencies>
                    <!-- Specify the dependent jdbc driver here -->
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
                        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
                        <version>${postgresql.jdbc.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>

                <!-- Common configuration shared by all executions -->
                <configuration>
                    <driver>org.postgresql.Driver</driver>
                    <url>jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432:spozz_db</url>
                    <username>postgres</username>
                    <password>root</password>
                    <!-- You can comment out username/password configurations and have maven 
                        to look them up in your settings.xml using ${settingsKey} -->
                    <settingsKey>sensibleKey</settingsKey>
                    <!-- All executions are ignored if -Dmaven.test.skip=true -->
                    <skip>${maven.test.skip}</skip>
                </configuration>

                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>test-compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>operation</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <!-- Specific configurations -->
                        <configuration>
                            <type>CLEAN_INSERT</type>
                            <src>src/test/resources/spozz_db_testdata.xml</src>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>

            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals><goal>copy-dependencies</goal></goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>

        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>

                <!-- M2Eclipse Compatibility -->
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                    <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.0</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                            <pluginExecutions>
                                <pluginExecution>
                                    <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                                        <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                                        <versionRange>[2.4,)</versionRange>
                                        <goals>
                                            <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                                        </goals>
                                    </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <action>
                                        <execute />
                                    </action>
                                </pluginExecution>
                            </pluginExecutions>
                        </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

If these are regular tests, which are executed in the `test` phase, then the fact that you're starting jetty in the `pre-integration-test` is your problem. You should be running it in the `test-compile` phase.

Comment: Updated my *pom.xml* file so that jetty starts in `test-compile` and stops in `test` phase. However, now I get two new errors. `Failure: Address already in use` and `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/jasper/runtime/JspApplicationContextImpl`, but `ps -ef | grep 5000 | xargs kill` did not find a service running on port 5000 to be canceled. And there seems to be another connection error: `[WARNING] failed SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:8080
java.net.BindException: Address already in use`

Comment: Running Maven in debug mode starts Maven on port 5000, if I recall correctly. Try starting Jetty on 8080, or something else.

Comment: Thanks, switching to an other port and changing the phase helped. However, I still have problems including JSP. Thus, I updated my `pom.xml` (appended in my post) to use a newer version of jetty. Now I am getting new errors. So I went to GitHub and browsed other projects until I found [this one](https://github.com/jetty-project/embedded-jetty-jsp). Now I am confused, since it seems that in newer versions it is not necessary to provide a `web.xml` in the `webapp/WEB-INF` folder of the project. So my question is if this is the new way to implement JAX-RS based webservices that use JSP.